# How to move the window titlebar icons for maximize, minimize and close to the left in MATE?

Tags: 16.04, icons, window, mate, titlebar

I just installed MATE on 16.04 and I would like to move the maximize, minimize and close buttons to the left, as I am used to this placement. I can't seem to find this sort of option in the MATE Control Center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **MATE Tweak** in **System > Preferences > Look and Feel**

[image]

Under **Windows**, select **Contemporary (Left)**

[image]

Placement will change instantly (I also like the buttons on the left).

Answer (score 1):

Use the dconf editor which should be provided. Applications > System Tools > dconf Editor. Select org > mate > marco > general > button-layout > menu:minimize,maximize,close for right side, minimize,maximize,close:menu for left side. You can also add spacer to separate any of the buttons.